# Javascript checking if username already exists(duplicate)

Tags: javascript, html

I created a function that checks if the username already exists in the data list, but alert shows every time even if the username isn't in duplicate data list.

```
<form onsubmit="return validation()">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="user" name="user"></td>
                <datalist id="list">
                    <option value="Tilen">
                    <option value="Marko">
                    <option value="Teja">
                    <option value="Tisa">
                    <option value="Rok">
                    <option value="Luka">
                    <option value="Mojca">
                </datalist>
            </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script>
   function validation(){
       var user = document.getElementById("user");
            if(user.value.length <= 20 && user.value.length >= 3){
            }
            else{
                alert("Username has to be between 3-20 characters.")
             }
            //duplication data list
            var user = document.getElementById("user");
            if(user.value == list.value){
            }
            else{
                alert("Username already exists.")
             }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: where do you populate the `list` variable in the function?

Comment: @Jhecht oh my bad, do I have to make variable for list "var list = document.getElementById("list");" too right?

Comment: Agreed with the above comment.  You first need to get "list" like you do with the "user" field.  Then you need to see if user.value is contained in "list", not that it equals "list".

Comment: you would need to populate `list`, but doing `document.querySelector('list')` would not do what you are expecting. I suggest you look up the Document Object Model before continuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the `options` using `querySelector`, iterate over them and compare then with `user.value`. Also you need `list="polje_imen"` in the `input` element.

```js
function validacija() {

  let user = document.getElementById('user');
  let listOptions = document.querySelectorAll("#list option");


  if (user.value.length <= 20 && user.value.length >= 3) {} else {
    alert("Username has to be between 3-20 characters.")
  }


  for (let i = 0; i < listOptions.length; i++) {
    if (listOptions[i].value === user.value) {
      alert('The name already exist')
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validacija()">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" list="list"></td>
      <datalist id="list">
                    <option value="Tilen">
                    <option value="Marko">
                    <option value="Teja">
                    <option value="Tisa">
                    <option value="Rok">
                    <option value="Luka">
                    <option value="Mojca">
                </datalist>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Edit: If you do not want to show the datalist, just use javascript.

```js
function validacija() {

  let user = document.getElementById('user');
  let listNames = ["Tilen","Marko","Teja","Tisa","Rok","Luka","Mojca"];


  if (user.value.length <= 20 && user.value.length >= 3) {} else {
    alert("Username has to be between 3-20 characters.")
  }


  for (let i = 0; i < listNames.length; i++) {
    if (listNames[i] === user.value) {
      alert('The name already exist')
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validacija()">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="user" name="user"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think you're binding to the input on the datalist correctly. You can actually use the datalist as an autocomplete for the input if you simply change your input to look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="upor_ime" name="upor_ime" list="polje_imen">
```

If you have that in there, it becomes much more obvious if they choose a value that is not in the list or not from a visual perspective. Now when it comes to validating it in javascript, if you still want to take it that far, you're going to have to break out your list of possible names into an array so you can check to see if the string you're entering in the input exists in the array of strings. Because you're trying to compare an array of strings to a string, using the `==` operator in an if statement will not work. Here's a possible solution:

```
<form onsubmit="return validacija()">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Uporabniško ime:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="upor_ime" name="upor_ime" list="polje_imen"></td>
                <datalist id="polje_imen"></datalist>
            </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script>
  var names = ["Tilen", "Marko", "Teja", "Tisa", "Rok", "Luka", "Mojca"];
  var options = "";
  for (let name of names) {
    options += "<option value='" + name + "'>";
  }
    document.getElementById("polje_imen").innerHTML = options;
  function validacija(){
    var upor_ime = document.getElementById("upor_ime");
    if(upor_ime.value.length > 20 || upor_ime.value.length < 3){
      alert("Uporabniško ime mora imeti med 3-20 znakov.")
      return;
    }

    //duplication data list
    var polje_imen = document.getElementById("polje_imen");
    if(names.includes(upor_ime.value)) {
      alert("Uporabniško ime že obstaja.");
      return;
    } else{
      // success        
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4f1hztr2/

Edit: I also changed around some of your if statement logic so that if the length of the item wasn't right it didn't continue executing the rest of the code.

Comment: I want to have text field as input not a list. I tried just creating an array in script as you did and then checking if the inputed name is the same as name in an array, but it doesn't work. I'm trying to create something simple, but don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Then just remove this from the input: `list="polje_imen"`.. everything else should work as you expect.